# JSF ajax reload whole page from dropdown

Tags: ajax, jsf, drop-down-menu

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="dropdownDevice"
        value="#{skinningBean.currentDevice}" converter="SkinConverter">
        <f:selectItems value="#{skinningBean.myDevicesSI}" var="c"
            itemValue="#{c}" />
        <f:ajax event="change" render="preview" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Is it possible to reload the whole page within this dropdown?  i need this because, I also need to reload a javascript when another device was selected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're not clear on if you would like to perform it synchronously or asynchronously.

If asynchronously, specify a render of `@all`.

```
<f:ajax ... render="@all" />
```

If synchronously, replace `<f:ajax>` by JS `form.submit()` call.

```
<h:selectOneMenu ... onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

Comment: Seems both methods do not reload the whole page. Javascript isn't working then. (I'm using a slider for divs, which is destroyed when i rerender something, so I have to reload the whole page)

Comment: If even the synchronous approach doesn't work, then your concrete problem is caused elsewhere. Hard to tell without having an SSCCE. Perhaps you need PRG?

Comment: what if I want to to do the same plus executing a function ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simple by setting `render="@all"` attribute in `f:ajax` tag:

```
<f:ajax render="@all" />
```

You can remove `event="change"` as it is default.